# How to filter an ordered list stored into a string

Tags: bash

Is it possible in bash to filter out a part of a string with another given string ?

I have a fixed list of motifs defined in a string. The order IS important and I want to keep only the parts that are passed as a parameter ?

```
myDefaultList="s,t,a,c,k"  #order is important
toRetains="k,t,c,u"  #provided by the user, order is not enforced

retained=filter $myDefaultList $toRetains # code to filter

echo $retained  # will print t,c,k"
```

I can write an ugly method that will use IFS, arrays and loops, but I wonder if there's a 'clever' way to do that, using built-in commands ?

Comment: what about sed?

Comment: Doing this in Bash seems like a bad choice. It should be trivial in Python and reasonably straightforward in Awk.

Comment: If you want to use Bash, an array would be a much better data type than a string. Converting between the two is of course easy, so if you want to expose strings, you could still use arrays internally.

Comment: I don't mind doing it with sed / awk inside the bash, but I really don't know these tools. I've often seen oneliner of awk or sed inside bash so I guess this is a common practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is another approach

```
tolines() { echo $1 | tr ',' '\n'; }
grep -f <(tolines "$toRetains") <(tolines "$myDefaultList") | paste -sd,
```

will print

```
t,c,k
```

assign to a variable as usual.

Comment: Better to change the name of the function since `split` is an existed utility to split lines in most systems

Comment: You'll still want to add quotes in `echo "$1"`, otherwise input which contains shell metacharacters will be munged.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention in your comments that you are open to sed/awk , check also this with GNU awk:

```
$ echo "$a"
s,t,a,c,k

$ echo "$b"
k,t,c,u

$ awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{printf("%s%s",$1,RT)}' <(echo "$b") <(echo "$a")
t,c,k
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

myDefaultList="s,t,a,c,k"
toRetains="s,t,c,u"

IFS=","
for i in $myDefaultList
do
        echo $toRetains | grep $i > /dev/null
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
        then
                retained=$retained" "$i
        fi
done

echo $retained | sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/,//1'
```

I have checked it running for me. Kindly check.

Comment: Prints it without the colon (`,`) idk if that's relevant for OP.

Comment: @M.Becerra please check :)

Comment: Quotes missing here, too. See [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119952/how-to-filter-an-ordered-list-stored-into-a-string#comment73323606_43120597).